# Orchard Core CMS Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, orchardcms, orchard-modules

I using Orchard Core CMS (1.0.0-rc2-13809) and SQL Server 2017. I create module where in controller I try to create paging:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(PagerParameters pagerParameters)
    {
        var siteSettings = await _siteService.GetSiteSettingsAsync();
        var pager = new Pager(pagerParameters, siteSettings.PageSize);

        var query = _session.Query<ContentItem, ContentItemIndex>();
        query = query.With<ContentItemIndex>(x => x.ContentType == contentType);
        query = query.With<ContentItemIndex>(x => x.Published);
        query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.PublishedUtc);

        var maxPagedCount = siteSettings.MaxPagedCount;
        if (maxPagedCount > 0 && pager.PageSize > maxPagedCount)
            pager.PageSize = maxPagedCount;

        var routeData = new RouteData();
        var pagerShape = (await New.Pager(pager)).TotalItemCount(maxPagedCount > 0 ? maxPagedCount : await query.CountAsync()).RouteData(routeData);

        var pageOfContentItems = await query.Skip(pager.GetStartIndex()).Take(pager.PageSize).ListAsync();
        IEnumerable<ContentItem> model = await query.ListAsync();

        var contentItemsSummaries = new List<dynamic>();

        foreach (var contentItem in pageOfContentItems)
        {
            contentItemsSummaries.Add(await _contentItemDisplayManager.BuildDisplayAsync(contentItem, _updateModelAccessor.ModelUpdater, "Summary"));
        }

        var viewModel = new ListContentsViewModel
        {
            ContentItems = contentItemsSummaries,
            Pager = pagerShape
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

And on the line `IEnumerable<ContentItem> model = await query.ListAsync();`, I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'. Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement

Comment: My first guess would be that you're not pointing at a SQL Server 2017 server - are you sure your connection string is pointing to the right database?  If so, does the query definitely work if you comment out all the lines relating to paging?

Comment: @JamieBurns - i find error, i use ListAsync() twice